# getting start time and end time values from select options with formArray Angular8

Tags: angular

In my form group, there are start time and end time select options in form array,I want to update the end time array on the basis of start time.

```
<div [formGroupName]="skillIndex">

          Start at:
            <select  formControlName="skill"  id="skill">
             <option value="0" selected>Select</option>
              <option [value]="type" *ngFor="let type of startTimeArray">
                {{type}}
              </option>
           </select>
           End at:
          <select  formControlName="exp" id="exp">
             <option value="0" selected>Select</option>
              <option [value]="type" *ngFor="let type of endTimeArray">
                {{type}}
              </option>
          </select>
     </div>
</div>
```

suppose the user select start time as 9AM, then the end time array values in select should go from 10AM to 8PM, like the dropdown for end time should show time between 10AM TO 8PM. now the user select end time to be 1PM.

and when the user presses, "add timing"another start time and end time select options appear,
here in the start time array, timings should be from 2PM to 8PM, again if the user selects start time as, say 3 PM, the end time array should be between 4PM TO 8PM..and so on if user presses "add timing" again
(skill is basically my start time and exp is my end time )

It's a little complicated to explain, please have a look at the stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r2sv3k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You has two problems,

1.- Change the options in select

2.- check when you change a value of the array if it's all correct.

First of all, I change your array startTimeArray making an array of object with value and text. The array is like

```
  timeArray:any=[
     {value:700,text:"07:00 AM"},
     {value:800,text:"08:00 AM"},
     ...
     {value:1200,text: "12:00 PM"},
     {value:1300,text:  "1:00 PM"}
     ...
  ]
```

this allow as make simple conditions because we can compare "value" (that's numbers), else if difficult know is "1:00PM" is greater than "12:00 AM" in a simple comparision

So, we can use a *ngIf to show the select. be carefull! use [ngValue] -not [value] to get a number, and I use null to indicate Select

```
  <div [formGroupName]="skillIndex">
      {{skillIndex}}
      Start at:
        <select  formControlName="skill"  id="skill">
         <option [ngValue]="null" selected>Select</option>
         <ng-container *ngFor="let type of timeArray" >
          <option [ngValue]="type.value" 
              *ngIf="!skillIndex || 
                 employeeSkills(empIndex).value[skillIndex-1].exp<type.value">
            {{type.text}}
          </option>
          </ng-container>
       </select>
       End at:
      <select  formControlName="exp" id="exp">
         <option [ngValue]="null" selected>Select</option>
         <ng-container *ngFor="let type of timeArray">
          <option [ngValue]="type.value" 
             *ngIf="employeeSkills(empIndex).value[skillIndex].skill<type.value" >
            {{type.text}}
          </option>
         </ng-container>
      </select>
```

see the conditions `*ngIf="!skillIndex || employeeSkills(empIndex).value[skillIndex-1].exp<type.value"` and `*ngIf="employeeSkills(empIndex).value[skillIndex].skill<type.value"`. We use `ng-container` because we need use a *ngFor and a *ngIf and we can not use in the same "tag"

Well, the other part is control when we change the array. This we need make in the function newEmploye

```
  newEmployee(): FormGroup {
    const group=this.fb.group({
      firstName: "",
      lastName: [{value:'', disabled:true}],
      option1: [{value:false, disabled:true}],
      option2: [{value:false, disabled:true}],
      option3: [{value:false, disabled:true}],
      skills: this.fb.array([]),
      options: this.fb.array([])
    });
    group.get('skills').valueChanges.subscribe(res=>{
       res.forEach((x:any,index:number)=>{
         if (x.exp<x.skill)
         {
             const skill=(group.get('skills') as FormArray).at(index)
             skill.get('exp').setValue(null,{emitEvent:false})
         }
         if (index>0 && x.skill<res[index-1].exp)
         {
             const skill=(group.get('skills') as FormArray).at(index)
             skill.get('skill').setValue(null,{emitEvent:false})
         }


       })
    })
    return group;
  }
```

See how we create a variable `const group` and return `group`. Before subscribe to valueChanges

your [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3bl4ui?file=src/app/app.component.ts) (remove unnecesary functions)

Comment: Thank you so much, this works, But i am trying to get values to time in 24hr formar, like 07:00, 8:00.....15:00.. the "value" is not getting saved in that format

Comment: just change the values as "07:00" (not 700). If you use a string HH:MM (always two digits for hour and two digits form minutes and 03:00 PM as "15:00", you can use the same code only change the value property for strings

Comment: if i change the value in timeArray form 700 to "07:00", then it wont be able to compare numbers

Comment: no, you need change all the values, the arrayTime becomes like `[{value:"07:00",text:"07:00 AM"},{value:"08:00",text:"08:00 AM"},{value:"09:00",text: "09:00 AM"},{value:"10:00",text: "10:00 AM"},{value:"11:00",text: "11:00 AM"},{value:"12:00",text: "12:00 PM"},{value:"13:00",text:  "1:00 PM"},{value:"14:00",text:  "2:00 PM"},{value:"15:00",text: "3:00 PM"},{value:"16:00",text:  "4:00 PM"},{value:"17:00",text: "5:00 PM"},{value:"18:00",text:  "6:00 PM"},{value:"19:00",text: "7:00 PM"},{value:"20:00",text: "8:00 PM"}]`

Comment: and change also setValue(null) bt setValue(''), see the https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nrqgj5?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your stackblitz, if the changes are there it will solve your issue, else you can replace the respected files with the code below.

Replace your html with this :

```
<form [formGroup]="empForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

    <div formArrayName="employees">

        <div *ngFor="let employee of employees().controls; let empIndex=index">

            <div [formGroupName]="empIndex" style="border: 1px solid blue; padding: 10px; width: 600px; margin: 5px;">
                {{empIndex}}
                First Name :
                <input type="text" formControlName="firstName">
         <label class="checkbox-inline">
                      <input type="checkbox" (change)="allow(empIndex, $event)" />ALLOW
        </label>

                <div>

        Last Name:
                <input type="text" formControlName="lastName">
                    <label class="checkbox-inline"  *ngFor="let day of days; ">
                        <input
                          type="checkbox"
                          formControlName="{{ day.name }}"
                          name="{{ day.name }}"
                           (change)="onChange(empIndex,day.value , $event.target.checked)"
                        />{{ day.value }}
                      </label>
                </div>
                <button (click)="removeEmployee(empIndex)">Remove</button>


                <div formArrayName="skills">

                    <div *ngFor="let skill of employeeSkills(empIndex).controls; let skillIndex=index">



                        <div [formGroupName]="skillIndex">
                            {{skillIndex}}


              Start at:
                <select (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)" formControlName="skill"  id="skill">
                 <option value="0" selected>Select</option>
                  <option  [value]="i" *ngFor="let type of startTimeArray; let i = index">
                    {{type}}
                  </option>
               </select>
               End at:
              <select *ngIf="enableEndTime" formControlName="exp" id="exp">
                 <option value="0" selected>Select</option>
                  <option [value]="type" *ngFor="let type of tempEndTimeArray">
                    {{type}}
                  </option>
              </select>




                            <button (click)="removeEmployeeSkill(empIndex,skillIndex)">Remove</button>

                            <pre>{{skillIndex.value |json}}</pre>
                        </div>

                    </div>


                    <button type="button" (click)="addEmployeeSkill(empIndex)">Add timings</button>
                </div>


            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <p>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </p>

</form>



<p>
    <button type="button" (click)="addEmployee()">Add Employee</button>
</p>

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">first name</th>
            <th scope="col">last name</th>
            <th scope="col">skill and exp</th>
            <th scope="col">days</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <!-- selected day -->
            <td></td>
        </tr>



    </tbody>
</table>
<pre>Form values: {{empForm.value | json}}</pre>
```

and your TS File with this:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { FormGroup, FormArray, FormBuilder, FormControl } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  forTableArray: any = [];
 startTimeArray:any=["07:00 AM","08:00 AM", "09:00 AM", "10:00 AM", "11:00 AM", "12:00 PM",  "1:00 PM",  "2:00 PM", "3:00 PM",  "4:00 PM", "5:00 PM",  "6:00 PM", "7:00 PM", "8:00 PM"];
  endTimeArray:any=["07:00 AM","08:00 AM", "09:00 AM", "10:00 AM", "11:00 AM", "12:00 PM",  "1:00 PM",  "2:00 PM", "3:00 PM",  "4:00 PM", "5:00 PM",  "6:00 PM", "7:00 PM", "8:00 PM"];
  public tempEndTimeArray: Array<any>;
  title = "Nested FormArray Example Add Form Fields Dynamically";
  public enableEndTime: boolean = false;
  selectedEmp = 0;
  empForm: FormGroup;
  days: any = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "option1",
      isActive: false,

      value: "option1"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "option2",
      isActive: false,

      value: "option2"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "option3",
      isActive: false,

      value: "option3"
    }
  ];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.empForm = this.fb.group({
      employees: this.fb.array([])
    });
  }

  employees(): FormArray {
    return this.empForm.get("employees") as FormArray;
  }

  onChange(empIndex, day: string, isChecked: boolean) {
    const dayFormArray = (this.empForm.get("employees") as FormArray)
      .at(empIndex)
      .get("options") as FormArray;
    if (isChecked) {
      dayFormArray.push(new FormControl(day));
    } else {
      let index = (dayFormArray.value as []).findIndex(item => item === day);
      dayFormArray.removeAt(index);
    }
  }
  newEmployee(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      firstName: "",
      lastName: [{value:'', disabled:true}],
      option1: [{value:false, disabled:true}],
      option2: [{value:false, disabled:true}],
      option3: [{value:false, disabled:true}],
      skills: this.fb.array([]),
      options: this.fb.array([])
    });
  }

allow(index,event){
  const status = event.target.checked ? 'enable' : 'disable' ;
  this.employees().at(index).get('lastName')[status]();
    this.employees().at(index).get('option1')[status]();
      this.employees().at(index).get('option2')[status]();
        this.employees().at(index).get('option3')[status]();
        if(!event.target.checked){
  this.employees().at(index).get('lastName')['reset']();
    this.employees().at(index).get('option1')['reset'](false);
      this.employees().at(index).get('option2')['reset'](false);
        this.employees().at(index).get('option3')['reset'](false);
 this.employees().at(index).get('options')['reset']("");

        }
}

  addEmployee() {
    console.log("Adding a employee");
    this.employees().push(this.newEmployee());
  }

  removeEmployee(empIndex: number) {
    this.employees().removeAt(empIndex);
  }

  employeeSkills(empIndex: number): FormArray {
    return this.employees()
      .at(empIndex)
      .get("skills") as FormArray;
  }

  newSkill(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      skill: "",
      exp: "",
      fromT:"",
      toT:""
    });
  }

  addEmployeeSkill(empIndex: number) {
    this.employeeSkills(empIndex).push(this.newSkill());
  }

  removeEmployeeSkill(empIndex: number, skillIndex: number) {
    this.employeeSkills(empIndex).removeAt(skillIndex);
  }

  onSubmit() {
    const employee = this.employees().value.map((_, i: number) =>
      this.mapFormEmployee(i)
    );
    const body = {
      displayText: true,
      employee: employee
    };
    this.forTableArray = body;
    console.log(body);
  }

  private mapFormEmployee(
    empIndex: number
  ): {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    option1: boolean;
    option2: boolean;
    option3: boolean;
    options:[];
    skills: { skill: string; exp: string }[];
  } {
    const employeeFormGroup = this.employees().at(empIndex);

    return {
      firstName: employeeFormGroup.get("firstName").value,
      lastName: employeeFormGroup.get("lastName").value,
      option1: employeeFormGroup.get("option1").value,
      option2: employeeFormGroup.get("option2").value,
      option3: employeeFormGroup.get("option3").value,
      options: employeeFormGroup.get("options").value,
      skills: employeeFormGroup
        .get("skills")
        .value.map((_, skillIndex) => this.mapFormSkill(empIndex, skillIndex))
    };
  }

  private mapFormSkill(
    empIndex: number,
    skillIndex: number
  ): { skill: string; exp: string } {
    const employeeFormGroup = this.employees().at(empIndex);
    const skillFormGroup = (employeeFormGroup.get("skills") as FormArray).at(
      skillIndex
    );

    return {
      skill: skillFormGroup.get("skill").value,
      exp: skillFormGroup.get("exp").value
    };
  }

  employeeFirstName(empIndex: number): string {
    return this.employees()
      .at(empIndex)
      .get("firstName").value;
  }

  employeeLastName(empIndex: number): string {
    return this.employees()
      .at(empIndex)
      .get("lastName").value;
  }
  getEmployeeSkill(employeeIdx: number, skillIdx: number) {
    const employee = this.empForm.value.employees[employeeIdx];
    if (employee === undefined) return null;
    return employee.skills.length === 0
      ? null
      : employee.skills.map(skill => skill.skill)[skillIdx];
  }

  getEmployeeExp(employeeIdx: number, skillIdx: number) {
    const employee = this.getEmployeeFormGroup(employeeIdx);
    return employee.value.skills.map(skill => skill.skill);
  }

  getEmployeeSkills(index: number): string[] {
    const employee = this.getEmployeeFormGroup(index);
    return employee.value.skills.map(skill => skill.skill);
  }

  private getEmployeeFormGroup(index: number): FormGroup {
    return this.employees().at(index) as FormGroup;
  }
public onSelect(val){
  console.log(val)
  let index = parseInt(val) + 1;
  console.log(index)
  this.enableEndTime = true;
  this.tempEndTimeArray = this.endTimeArray.slice(index);

}
}


export class country {
  id: string;
  name: string;

  constructor(id: string, name: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }
}
  // onCheckChange(event){
  //   const formArray: FormArray = this.empForm.get('myChoices') as FormArray
  //    if(event.target.checked){
  //     // Add a new control in the arrayForm
  //     formArray.push(new FormControl(event.target.value));
  //   }else{
  //      let i: number = 0;
  //  formArray.controls.forEach((ctrl: FormControl) => {
  // if(ctrl.value == event.target.value) {
  //         // Remove the unselected element from the arrayForm
  //         formArray.removeAt(i);
  //         return;
  //       }

  //       i++;
  //  });
  //   }
  // }
  // get selectedOptions() { // right now: ['1','3']
  //     return this.days
  //               .filter(opt => opt.checked)
  //               .map(opt => opt.value)
  //   }
```

Comment: thank you so much, this works for the first start and end time, yes

Comment: You are welcome! Please upvote the solution/ comment above by pressing the up arrow.

Comment: yes, right now my reputation low, so its not showing. once my reputation is more, I will come back to this and upvote

Comment: How would you get selected time value?

Answer (score 0):

Hello check this solution with ngModel change and one more Array for the available end times:
  html:

```
Start at:
            <select  formControlName="skill"  id="skill"  [(ngModel)]="selectedStartTime" (ngModelChange)="onRefresh()" >
             <option [ngValue]="null" selected>Select</option>
              <option [ngValue]="type" *ngFor="let type of startTimeArray">
                {{type}}
              </option>
           </select>
           End at:
          <select  formControlName="exp" id="exp">
             <option value="0" selected>Select</option>
              <option [value]="type" *ngFor="let type of availableEndTimes">
                {{type}}
              </option>
          </select>
```

and in yout ts file:

```
selectedStartTime;
 availableEndTimes= [];
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.empForm = this.fb.group({
      employees: this.fb.array([])
    });
    this.selectedStartTime= null;
  }
    onRefresh(){
  this.availableEndTimes = [...this.endTimeArray];
  let index =this.endTimeArray.indexOf(this.selectedStartTime);
   this.availableEndTimes.splice(0,index+1);
  console.log("available times",this.availableEndTimes);
}
```

The main idea is thar the selectedStartTime variable holds the value of the start time.
The availableEndTimes array is a array that at start is a copy of endTimeArray(contains all the available times). As user selects a start time we splice(removing unwanted values in refresh() function) the availableEndTimes array(that will be now shown to our second select box).

Comment: it's innecesary add so quantity of new variables and, really I think is to a good idea mixin [(ngModel)] and formControl over the same input

Comment: Yes you are right this is best to use without form but with ng model and submit the ng model at a submit function.